# Kafka MultiBroker on different machines are not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, messagebroker

I am implementing a Kafka cluster architecture with 2 brokers and 2 zookeepers in two machines connected locally

Machine1(10.0.215.22) : (Hidding trival properties)
Kakfa -> Server.properties

```
port=9094
broker.id=1
num.partitions=1
zookeeper.connect=10.0.215.22:2181,10.0.229.48:2181
delete.topic.enable = true
auto.create.topics.enable=true
```

Zookeeper ->

```
clientPort=2181
server.1=10.0.215.22:2888:3888
server.2=10.0.229.48:2888:3888
```

Machine2(10.0.229.48) :  (Hidding trival properties)Kakfa -> Server.properties
          Kakfa -> Server.properties

```
port=9094
broker.id=2
num.partitions=1
zookeeper.connect=10.0.215.22:2181,10.0.229.48:2181
delete.topic.enable = true
auto.create.topics.enable=true
```

Zookeeper ->

```
clientPort=2181
server.1=10.0.215.22:2888:3888
server.2=10.0.229.48:2888:3888
```

After starting zookeeper on both machines i starts kafka brokers

Then i use this to create topic from machine 1

```
kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --c~reate --zookeeper 10.0.215.22:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2 --topic test
Created topic "test".


kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.0.215.22:2181 --topic test --describe

Topic:test  PartitionCount:2    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:


    Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2,1
    Topic: test Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1
```

Then using the console producer:

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 10.0.229.48:9094 --topic test
```

> test
>   [2018-04-19 17:00:55,994] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {test=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>   [2018-04-19 17:00:56,098] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {test=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>   [

I get this above error when i am trying to produce msg from machine 1 to machine 2's broker

My Machine is connected locally via LAN and i can easily connect machine 2 via ssh and vise-versa there is no network issue

Comment: First of all, Zookeeper should be configured with odd number of nodes.

Comment: Excuse me: what is this question doing with Spring?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous  i tried with only one zookeeper its still not working

Comment: @ArtemBilan i have implemented that same senario with spring  in which i am producing msg from producer code which is written in java+spring im using spring-kafka jar for that and getting same error

Comment: Well, Spring Kafka is fully based on the Apache Kafka client and if you have such a problem even with the `console-producer`, we can't help you from the Spring level. That's why I found the `spring` and `spring-kafka` tags here as a bit suspicious.